# python: how to delete row and modify specific list string from CSV

Tags: python, parsing, csv

This is my first time posting a question so I apologise in advance if I make any mistakes.

I am currently attempting to create a custom python program (pretty much a parser) that takes in data as such:

```
junk
junk
junk
junk
junk
junk
fields       title   title   title
data_type   d_type  d_type  d_type
data1   data2    data 3
data4   data 5   data6
data7   data8    data9
junk
```

Where my desired output is:

```
title   title   title
data1   data2   data3
data4   data5   data6
data7   data8   data9
```

Here is the working portion of my code that I have thus far:

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('file.log','rb') as csvfile:
    rowlist = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in itertools.islice(rowlist,6,12):   
    print row
```

Whenever the above code is run it produces a series of lists as seen here

```
['fields','title1', 'title2', 'title3']
['data_type','d_type','d_type', 'd_type']
['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
['data4', 'data5', 'data6']
['data7', 'data8', 'data9']
```

The the first data entry (data1, data4, data7) in the list is always a number whereas the other data entries may be any string/number/character.

The `itertools` has solved cutting off the top and bottom of the file, however I am still struggling to

- delete the "data_type line"
- removing 'fields', that is:
  ['fields','title1', 'title2', 'title3']----->['title1', 'title2', 'title3']

I have seen some solutions that remove lines/overwrite line however, I  do not have a lot of memory to spare thus I must keep opening/closing/writing to a minimum. Any and all help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: We have no idea what determines whether a line should be included or excluded.

Comment: So why not just do `if row[0] == 'fields': row = row[1:]` and `if row[0] == 'data_type': continue`?

Comment: You can filter your iterable further with `itertools.ifilterfalse` https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse.

Comment: Probably a sample csv file may help to understand the problem better. You could delete the data_type row in 'for' loop, right? Delete item from the list in the for loop as well using : if 'fields' in mylist: mylist.remove('fields')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice each row:

```
  for row in islice(rowlist, 6, 12):
    if row[0] == "data_type":
        continue
    elif row[0] == "fields":
          print(row[1:])
    else:
        print(row)
```

If you are just writing  rows use islice again:

```
for row in islice(rowlist, 6, 12):
    if row[0] == "data_type":
        continue
    elif row[0] == "fields":
         fileobj.write(islice(rowlist, 1,None))
    else:
        fileobj.write(row)
```

If you are actually trying to overwrite the original file, you can write the lines to a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and replace the original file with [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
    rowlist = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in islice(rowlist, 6, 12):
        if row[0] == "data_type":
            continue
        elif row[0] == "fields":
            temp.write(islice(rowlist, 1, None))
        else:
            temp.write(row)

move(temp.name,"file.csv")
```

Comment: Only one of the rows needs to have the first column removed.